# Installing grunt - did it install or not?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I tried installing grunt with `npm install grunt` but I'm not clear if `grunt` installed or not:

```
$ npm install grunt
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN template@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN template@0.0.1 No license field.
```

e.g.

```
$ grunt
-bash: grunt: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

You installed it locally in the directory that you run the install command.
You'll have to install it globally with the -g flag.
In the grunt web they recomend to install grunt-cli.
`npm install -g grunt-cli`
Depending on how you installed node you may want to add `sudo` to that command:
`sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`

Answer (score 1):

When you run `npm install`, the package is placed in the nearest `node_modules` directory, travelling up the directory tree.

So, `./node_modules` is the first candidate, `../node_modules` gets checked next, `../../node_modules` next and so on, until one is found.

To run a program installed in the nearest local `node_modules`, you can use `npm bin`, which resolves to the appropriate path:

```
$(npm bin)/grunt
```

This is the same as running (assuming `node_modules` in current working directory):

```
./node_modules/.bin/grunt
```

If you want to install `grunt` system-wide, and run it without any of this ceremony, run `npm install -g`

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
grunt # run without prefix
```

Note, however, that this enforces a single version of `grunt` across all of your projects, since they all share the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to see if `grunt` is installed:

```
npm list grunt
```

If you are installing your packages globally using `install -g`, then modify the command to use the `-g` flag:

```
npm list -g grunt
```

To see all top-level installed packages, use:

```
npm list --depth=0
```

Note that you can also use the `-g` flag for the above command as well.

Hope this helps!